# Adding context menu or dropdown menu in Sigma JS graph

Tags: javascript, sigma.js

What's the best or preferred way to add a dropdown or context menu in a Sigma JS graph that appears at the mouse-click position, over the graph itself? I've seen libraries like [contextmenu.js](http://ignitersworld.com/lab/contextMenu.html), but can it be done in a simpler or better way? My goal is to be able to click a node and then click a menu option, passing data from the node to functions called through click events on the menu.

Update: I've tried using [this jQuery context menu library](https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/), with the selector set to the ID of my Sigma container div. I can get a sample context menu to appear, but only if I click on the border of the div - clicking inside the graph doesn't display the context menu (double-clicking zooms the graph in, as before).

Answer (score 2):

I pieced together [Lili Cherbour's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48791445/1762224) by combining Sigma's *"Getting Started"* example with the Linkurious (now Ogma) tooltip example. It does not look like the hidden works, but if anyone can figure it out, feel free to fix this code.

```js
// Tooltip setup
var config = {
  node: [{
    show: 'hovers',
    hide: 'hovers',
    cssClass: 'sigma-tooltip',
    position: 'top',
    //autoadjust: true,
    template:
      '<div class="arrow"></div>' +
      '<div class="sigma-tooltip-header">{{label}}</div>' +
      '<div class="sigma-tooltip-body">' +
      '  <table>' +
      '    <tr><th>Name</th> <td>{{data.name}}</td></tr>' +
      '    <tr><th>Gender</th> <td>{{data.gender}}</td></tr>' +
      '    <tr><th>Age</th> <td>{{data.age}}</td></tr>' +
      '    <tr><th>City</th> <td>{{data.city}}</td></tr>' +
      '  </table>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="sigma-tooltip-footer">Number of connections: {{degree}} </div>',
    renderer: function(node, template) {
      // The function context is s.graph
      node.degree = this.degree(node.id);
      // Returns an HTML string:
      return Mustache.render(template, node);
    }
  }, {
    show: 'overNode',
    cssClass: 'sigma-tooltip',
    position: 'right',
    template:
      '<div class="arrow"></div>' +
      '<div class="sigma-tooltip-header">{{label}}</div>' +
      '<div class="sigma-tooltip-body">' +
      '  <p>Context menu for {{neo4j_labels}}</p>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="sigma-tooltip-footer">Number of connections: {{degree}} </div>',
    renderer: function(node, template) {
      node.degree = this.degree(node.id);
      return Mustache.render(template, node);
    }
  }],
  stage: {
    template:
      '<div class="arrow"></div>' +
      '<div class="sigma-tooltip-header"> Menu </div>'
  }
};

var graphData = {
  "nodes": [
    { "id": "n0", "label": "Node #1", "x": 0, "y": 0, "size": 3 },
    { "id": "n1", "label": "Node #2", "x": 3, "y": 1, "size": 2 },
    { "id": "n2", "label": "Node #3", "x": 1, "y": 3, "size": 1 },
  ],
  "edges": [
    { "id": "e0", "source": "n0", "target": "n1" },
    { "id": "e1", "source": "n1", "target": "n2" },
    { "id": "e2", "source": "n2", "target": "n0" },
  ]
};

// Initialize the Sigma graph
const sigmaInstance = new sigma({ 
  graph: graphData,
  container: 'sigma-container',
  settings: {
    defaultNodeColor: '#ec5148'
  }
});

// Set initial zoom
sigmaInstance.cameras[0].goTo({ x: 1, y: 1, angle: 0, ratio: 2.0 });

// Instantiate the tooltips plugin with a Mustache renderer for node 
var tooltips = sigma.plugins.tooltips(sigmaInstance, sigmaInstance.renderers[0], config);

tooltips.bind('shown', function(event) {
  //console.log('tooltip shown');
});

tooltips.bind('hidden', function(event) {
  //console.log('tooltip hidden');
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #ddd;
}

.sigma-wrapper {
  max-width: 300px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #AAA;
  margin: auto;
}

#sigma-container {
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.sigma-tooltip {
  max-width: 240px;
  max-height: 280px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: auto;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.sigma-tooltip .icon {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}

.sigma-tooltip-header {
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-size: 120%;
  color: #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 10px;
}

.sigma-tooltip-body {
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-width: inherit;
  max-height: 180px;
}

.sigma-tooltip-body th {
  color: #999;
  text-align: left;
}

.sigma-tooltip-footer {
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #999;
}

.sigma-tooltip>.arrow {
  border-width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
}

.sigma-tooltip.top {
  margin-top: -12px;
}

.sigma-tooltip.top>.arrow {
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  border-top-color: #999;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}

.sigma-tooltip.bottom {
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.sigma-tooltip.bottom>.arrow {
  left: 50%;
  top: -10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  border-bottom-color: #999;
  border-top-width: 0;
}

.sigma-tooltip.left {
  margin-left: -12px;
}

.sigma-tooltip.left>.arrow {
  top: 50%;
  right: -10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  border-left-color: #999;
  border-right-width: 0;
}

.sigma-tooltip.right {
  margin-left: 12px;
}

.sigma-tooltip.right>.arrow {
  top: 50%;
  left: -10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  border-right-color: #999;
  border-left-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/2.3.0/mustache.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sigma.js/1.2.1/sigma.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/linkurious.js/1.5.1/plugins/sigma.plugins.tooltips.min.js"></script>
<div class="sigma-wrapper">
  <div id="sigma-container"></div>
</div>
```

#### References

- http://sigmajs.org/
- https://doc.linkurio.us/ogma/2.1.0/examples/tooltips-mustache.html
- https://github.com/Linkurious/linkurious.js/wiki/Tooltips

Answer (score 1):

I can create a context menu with the following code. [Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) was used as a templating engine for generating the HTML for the context menu.

```js
// Tooltip setup
var config = {
  node: [{
    show: 'hovers',
    hide: 'hovers',
    cssClass: 'sigma-tooltip',
    position: 'top',
    //autoadjust: true,
    template:
      '<div class="arrow"></div>' +
      '<div class="sigma-tooltip-header">{{label}}</div>' +
      '<div class="sigma-tooltip-body">' +
      '  <table>' +
      '    <tr><th>Name</th> <td>{{data.name}}</td></tr>' +
      '    <tr><th>Gender</th> <td>{{data.gender}}</td></tr>' +
      '    <tr><th>Age</th> <td>{{data.age}}</td></tr>' +
      '    <tr><th>City</th> <td>{{data.city}}</td></tr>' +
      '  </table>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="sigma-tooltip-footer">Number of connections: {{degree}} </div>',
    renderer: function(node, template) {
      // The function context is s.graph
      node.degree = this.degree(node.id);
      // Returns an HTML string:
      return Mustache.render(template, node);
    }
  }, {
    show: 'overNode',
    cssClass: 'sigma-tooltip',
    position: 'right',
    template:
      '<div class="arrow"></div>' +
      '<div class="sigma-tooltip-header">{{label}}</div>' +
      '<div class="sigma-tooltip-body">' +
      '  <p> Context menu for {{neo4j_labels}} </p>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="sigma-tooltip-footer">Number of connections: {{degree}} </div>',
    renderer: function(node, template) {
      node.degree = this.degree(node.id);
      return Mustache.render(template, node);
    }
  }],
  stage: {
    template:
      '<div class="arrow"></div>' +
      '<div class="sigma-tooltip-header"> Menu </div>'
  }
};

// Instantiate the tooltips plugin with a Mustache renderer for node 
var tooltips = sigma.plugins.tooltips(s, s.renderers[0], config);

tooltips.bind('shown', function(event) {
  console.log('tooltip shown', event);
});

tooltips.bind('hidden', function(event) {
  console.log('tooltip hidden', event);
});
```

Here is a screenshot

[image: ContextMenu Image]